# ¿Por qué un proceso simple de JAVA (Un bucle infinito que imprime "Hola mundo") utiliza 26 Threads y lo mismo en Python sólo ocupa 1 Thread?

Tags: java, python, hilos, rendimiento

¿Por qué un proceso simple de **Java** (Un bucle infinito que imprime "Hola mundo") utiliza 26 Threads y lo mismo en **Python** sólo ocupa 1 Thread?

¿No se supone que **Java** tiene mejor performance, es más rápido que Python y utiliza mejor los recursos? O estoy en lo incorrecto?

El código de cada programa es este:

**Java**:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    while(true) {
        System.out.println("Hola mundo");
    }
}
}
```

**Python**:

```
while(True):
print("Hola mundo")
```

Al correr ambas aplicaciones en paralelo esto es el resultado:

En cuanto a CPU:

[image: Uso CPU ambos programas]

En cuanto a Uso de Memoria:

[image: Uso de memoria programa java]

[image: Uso de memoria programa python]

¿Esto es por la máquina virtual de **Java**? y si es así, ¿esto no empeora el performance de la aplicación?

Me intriga que **Java** utilice 26 Threads sólo para hacer un while infinito y **Python** lo hace en un sólo Thread?

Si soy ignorante, saquenme de esa duda.

*NOTA: Se utiliza para este test **Java 10** y **Python 3.6***

Comment: Por ejemplo para un programa de Cyber Café que lleva corriendo de 15 a 30 cronómetros diferentes al mismo tiempo (Para controlar el tiempo de uso de cada PC) ???

Comment: Creo que la comparación no es objetiva. Cada lenguaje tiene su propósito y es mejor en un ámbito que en otros. Con respecto al número de hilos, algunos le pertenecen al programa y la mayoría a la JVM. Pero la JVM le facilita la portabilidad en un amplio número de plataformas/arquitecturas.

Comment: @MissionaryrobotRobot java podría ser perfecto para esto. Yo python lo veo mas para temas como aprendizaje de máquinas. Aquí hay un link donde enumeran algunos lenguajes y las áreas donde son mas utilizados: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/choose-programming-language

Comment: El tema del bajo performance de las aplicaciones Java es, a día de hoy, casi un mito. Recordar que desde hace varios años la máquina virtual de Java incorpora compilación JIT que permite compilar el bytecode a código nativo en tiempo de ejecución. Además en cada versión se agregan mejoras relativas al rendimiento. Debemos estar siempre actualizados para ir eliminando los mitos sobre Java, como aquel famoso que dice que es mejor utilizar StringBuilder en vez de concatenar Strings con el signo +.

Comment: Les recomiendo que leen [este artículo de la Java Magazine](http://www.javamagazine.mozaicreader.com/MarApr2018#&pageSet=94&page=0), en específico la pregunta 2 y su respectiva respuesta en [esta página](http://www.javamagazine.mozaicreader.com/MarApr2018#&pageSet=98&page=0)

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con @E. Betanzos, es posible que python sea mejor en performance que java o viceversa (no conozco python). Pero de eso a decir que es una basura, esta muy lejos de la verdad. Yo hice una aplicación en java que genero 32000 pdfs a partir de 32000 xml y lo hizo como en 8 minutos. Acabo de hacer otra que sube un txt a base de datos extrayendo campos de cadenas del archivo, convirtiendo tipos y haciendo inserts y sube como 74000 registros en 8 minutos. Ahora facebook tiene su chat en apache hadoop (java) con tiempo real y no creo que te quejes de que el chat de facebook esta lento

Comment: Por curiosidad, ¿qué pasa si ejecutas los programas de Java y Python varias veces (p.e. 10-15 veces)? ¿Cuántos procesos/threads hay en cada caso?

Comment: Pues lo proporcional, en Python si ejecuto 4 veces la aplicación (Por ejemplo) lo ejecuta en 4 Threads, y en JAVA pues 24 Threads por proceso. Osea muchos más, pero @Pablo Lozano ya me ha aclarado mis dudas, es estabilidad y menos consumo de memoria (Python) VS Rapidez en ejecución de las tareas (JAVA) y pues lo que por ahora busco para mi APP es rapidez. (Y creo que Java no se queda atrás en estabilidad tampoco)

Answer (score 4):

> ¿No se supone que Java tiene mejor performance, es más rápido que
>   Python y utiliza mejor los recursos? O estoy en lo incorrecto?

Como suele ocurrir en estos casos, la respuesta correcta no es sencilla. Vamos a analizar primero el concepto de rendimiento (o, en el término en inglés que has usado, *performance*):

Según la RAE, la segunda acepción de rendimiento es la que nos interesa:

> 2. m. Proporción entre el producto o el resultado obtenido y los medios utilizados.

No es que sea ambiguo, simplemente los medios a tener en cuenta son varios:

- uso de la CPU.
- uso de memoria.
- cantidad de tiempo empleado.

Imagina que tienes un programa con muchos cálculos que **quieres que tarde lo mínimo posible** en ejecutarse. Si tienes que elegir entre Java y Python, el elegido [siempre será Java](https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/faster/python.html).

Al contrario que el intérprete de Python, la JVM usará todos los recursos que pueda para optimizar el código, con compilación JIT, un recolector de basura muy optimizado, estudiando si puede dividir entre varios hilos el trabajo a realizar.. etc. Para ellos lanzará el hilo de tu programa y multitud de otros hilos que estudiarán el comportamiento del hilo principal, usando más memoria de la que necesitará éste por sí solo. Y seguramente cargará más la CPU, intentando aprovechar los tiempos muertos del hilo principal para realizar otros cálculos.

Por tanto, en velocidad, Java es muy superior a Python, pero **Python requiere menos memoria RAM**: la inicialización del programa en Java requiere cargar la JVM, que pesa mucho más que la máquina virtual de Python, con lo que para tareas muy pequeñas (de décimas de segundo), es posible que Python sea más rápido porque no necesita toda la infraestructura que tiene Java (tus capturas de pantalla lo dejan claro, 4 MB contra más de 100MB).
En cambio, si tienes una aplicación pesada, que ya de por sí necesitará varias GB de RAM y multitud de hilos, conexiones a otras máquinas y aplicaciones (bases de datos, por ejemplo), esos 100MB extras de RAM son insignificantes.

Comment: Cabe la posibilidad, de que la JVM tambien coloque el tamaño _(Por lo menos la mitad)_ de la memoria del monton para su propio uso? ¿O ésta memoria se "pide" a medida que el programa se ejecuta?